# Matplotlib Wind Barb plotting issues

Tags: python, matplotlib, weather

I have some code below, I am basically trying to plot wind barbs on a sounding plot

```
import urllib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def read_sounding(url):
    pressure=[]
    altitude=[]
    temp    =[]
    lines  = urllib.request.urlopen(url).readlines()
    for line in lines[10:76]:
        entries = line.decode("utf-8").split(" ")
        columns=[]
        for entry in entries:
            if len(entry) > 1: columns.append(entry)
        if len(columns) > 2: # otherwise data not available
            pressure.append(float(columns[0]))
            altitude.append(float(columns[1]))
            temp.append(float(columns[2]))
    return(pressure,altitude,temp)
def read_wind(url):
    wind = []
    lines  = urllib.request.urlopen(url).readlines()
    for line in lines[10:76]:
        entries = line.decode("utf-8").split(" ")
        columns=[]
        for entry in entries:
            if len(entry) > 1: columns.append(entry)
        if len(columns) > 2: # otherwise data not available
            wind.append(float(columns[7]))
    return(wind)
def location(url):
    lines  = urllib.request.urlopen(url).readlines()
    lon=lines[81] # longitude
    lat=lines[80] # latitude
    lon=float(lon.decode("utf-8").split(":")[1])
    lat=float(lat.decode("utf-8").split(":")[1])
    return(lat,lon)   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url    = 'http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=naconf&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR=2005&MONTH=07&FROM=0812&TO=0812&STNM=72469'
    p,h,t=read_sounding(url)
    lat,lon=location(url)
    W= read_wind(url)
    plt.plot(t,h,'o--')
    #print(W)
    plt.barbs(W)
    plt.xlabel("temperature [C]")
    plt.ylabel("altitude [m]")
    plt.title('lat='+str(lat)+' lon='+str(lon))
```

the error I get is in the line plt.barb and its an error that says "pop from empty list" even though when I print the returned value I have a list with numbers in it. I am able to produce a sounding plot for temperature but I need to add wind barbs to it. The link in the main function has all of the data in columns.
The exact error is "Index Error: pop from empty list"

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly. It should also contain the full traceback of the error message. The aim is to enable other users to reproduce your problem.

Comment: When I run this program it plots height over temperature. Now you want the corresponding wind direction and magnitude for each point?

Comment: [The documentation for `plt.barbs`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.barbs.html?highlight=barbs#matplotlib.axes.Axes.barbs) show that this function takes between 2 and 5 arrays as arguments. You are only passing one array, so things cannot work. However, I don't understand how the barbs relate to the other plot, so I cannot help any more than that